# JScrollPane border overlaps on JTable border

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside a `JScrollPane` and I am trying to hide the `ViewPortBorder` of the `JScrollPane`. To do so I set its border to an empty border, but it looks like it paints the empty border on the JTable outer border (left border of the first column).

How can I hide the `JScrollPane` border without hiding the `JTable` border? The problem is only for the left side, the borders don't overlap on the right side.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
    "Vegetarian"};

    Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                {"John", "Doe",
                    "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                    {"Sue", "Black",
                        "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"Jane", "White",
                            "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                            {"Joe", "Brown",
                                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);   
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scroll.setViewportBorder(border);
    scroll.setBorder(border);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scroll);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable` doesn't have a border, what you're seeing is the border provided by the scroll pane

(Without border/with border)

[image]

This is actually (one of the reasons) why the left side of the table doesn't have a grid line ;)

What you could do is apply a `MatteBorder` to the table

```
Color color = table.getGridColor();
table.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 0, color));
```

(Without border/with border)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct when you set the `JScrollPane` border to an empty border. However, what you see on the left border of your table is simply the way that the `JTable` elements are drawn. You will notice that if you just add the `JTable` by itself without putting it into a scroll pane that it draws it exactly the same way.

If you want to draw a line on the left side of your table you have to manually set the border.